# Angular Validator pattern not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation, angular-validator

I'm using angular reactive form. In a formControl of the formGroup I've set Validator.pattern with a Regex that's not working properly and I can't see why. I've validated the Regex on this site https://www.regextester.com/99144, to check it and it worked correctly

The Regex (Minimum eight characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character)

```
pattern = new RegExp(/^(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*\d)(?=\S*[^\w\s])\S{8,}$/gm)
```

This is the formGroup

```
   this.trocarASenhaForm = this.fb.group({
      UserId: [''],
      SenhaAtual: ['', [Validators.required, ]],
      NovaSenha: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.pattern)]],
      ConfirmaSenha: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.pattern)]]
    },{ validator: this.checkPasswords })
```

So, when I type for example "World@20" it validates true, but then when I start typing "World@201" it validates false, and it is intercalatable. "World@2010" it validates true again, "World@20100" it validates false and so forth

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The patterns seems to accep the value `'World@201'.match(pattern)` in the browser console. Can you reproduce this on stalkblitz?

Comment: Hi @BasheerKharoti yes I can. Here it is 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/validator-pattern-error?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: This Regex worked perfectly "/^(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*\d)(?=\S*[^\w\s])\S{8,}$/"

Comment: Because you removed the modifiers `gm`. It was even working this one `/^(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*\d)(?=\S*[^\w\s])\S{8,}$/i`

Comment: Yes @BasheerKharoti this one also worked. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
const pattern = '^(?=\\S*[a-z])(?=\\S*[A-Z])(?=\\S*\d)(?=\\S*[^\\w\\s])\\S{8,}$';
```

and

```
this.trocarASenhaForm = this.fb.group({
  UserId: [''],
  SenhaAtual: ['', [Validators.required]],
  NovaSenha: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern(pattern)]],
  ConfirmaSenha: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern(pattern)]]},
  { validator: this.checkPasswords }
)
```